# Как сделать так чтобы код после input() работал, даже если ничего ещё не ввели, но когда ввели, вызвать функцию(python)

Tags: python, input, while

Как сделать так чтобы код после input() работал, даже если ничего ещё не ввели, но когда ввели, вызвать функцию(python)

Comment: Ну это не `input` надо использовать, а модуль `keyboard`, например.

Comment: Вызовите функцию input, где она необходима.

Comment: В каком плане работала? Если без асинхронности, то можно после `inp = input()` поставить `if inp: вызов функции`. Или нужна асинхронность?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```
import threading
from time import sleep

def print_result(result):
   print('I have a message for you ' + result)

def wait_for_input(callback):
   value = input('give me> ')
   callback(value) 

thread = threading.Thread(target=wait_for_input, args=(print_result,))
thread.start()

counter = 1

while thread.is_alive():
   counter += 1
   sleep(1)

print("I was busy and counted to {}".format(counter))
```